# Show shipping charge in shopping cart

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart

I am still looking to see if this is possible or if anyone can do the work/extension available?

I have magento 1.9 2.1 If you are logged in as a guest and add an item to your shopping cart the shipping charge does not show up. where if you are logged in it appears.

my shipping is basic as i do not offer multiple shipping options, just spend under a certain amount and pay £* shipping or spend over a certain amount and get FREE shipping.

I was wondering if there is a way that allows any customer to see the shipping charge in there shopping cart before going through the checkout process

Many Thanks

Comment: May be this link can help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97433/517

Answer (score 3):

Try this extension; [integer-net/Autoshipping](https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping). It also gives you the option to change country using a select box. Please also see [this Github issue](https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping/issues/21) for a fix you'll likely need.

Or try this extension; [RapidCommerce_DefaultDestination](http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/en/blog/2012/04/allways-show-shipping-costs-in-magento/)